# Linux: keeping GUI responsive during low free memory

Tags: gui, out-of-memory

I just had it (it kind of solved itself for now, but took about 5-10 minutes): a situation which several minutes ago I was afraid could happen but still believed Linux optimally uses memory for caching and will free it when needed: https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/

> The catch over here is the cached and buffers column. The second line
>   tells that 4.6 GB is free. This is the free memory in first line added
>   with the buffers and cached amount of memory.
>
> Linux has the habit of caching lots of things for faster performance,
>   so that memory can be freed and used if needed.

Maybe so, only that apparently it does not think GUI is an important process that require such action and now one mouse cursor move takes about a minute. Some keyboard shortcuts remain working fine, i.e. changing keyboard light works instantly, but Ctl-Q to close currently on-screen firefox did not work (that is on another laptop from where I write it as you may have guessed).

Situation before I switched to firefox and could open couple of pages before the "freeze": free memory 200Kb,  buffers/cache 9Gb, free space in Documents folder as shown in file manager: 3.4 Gb. The system is Linux Mint Live booted `toram` with `swapoff`.

Now in about 10 minutes GUI returned to being responsive again, some how to questions I'd like to ask:

1. make Linux keep GUI responsive in low free memory situations? more broadly keep (also by proactive freeing) some amount of memory free to allow for quick launch of new appps?
2. know if system can free memory quickly (instantly for a
   human)?
3. configure to keep free some resources to allow to switch to other terminal to "help" the system to free memory.

There is general question I've just read (https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44684/why-dont-operating-systems-reserve-a-fixed-amount-of-resources-for-the-gui), but hope in particular system (Linux) there are some specific answers.

ADDED: I started video player and when I switched to file manager the system quickly became very slow to respond again. I starting to think maybe the system cannot free all cached 9Gb memory. But maybe 3.4Gb it can, what does it mean that I have 3.4Gb free space in Documents folder for system booted to ram?

Now about 30 minutes passed and the system has not returned to being responsive. I guess it is the video player tries to cache a file to play and take memory that become available. I tried Ctl-Alt-Fn to no effect, so I will wait some hours, maybe the system will get back to me. What else can I do except turn it off? Next time I want to try `sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` when system approaches low memory.

ADDED 2:

After good night break (about 10 hours) I found system responsive back. `drop_caches` did not help much, so I fell back to ordinary user tactic and restarted web browser, freeing about 2Gb.

Please help to learn how to check what amount of memory is taken by what and what memory can be freed by the kernel (as apparently my system DID returned to being responsive, on the other hand drop caches did not free 8Gb reported as cache by `free`):

Output of `free -m` before browser restart and it did not list buffers/cache separately as articles found on the web show, so also I post (more detailed) output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15740        4508        2366        8453        8865        2474

MemTotal:       16118172 kB
MemFree:          528472 kB
MemAvailable:     475820 kB
Buffers:            1588 kB
Cached:          8939100 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          6711540 kB
Inactive:        8440460 kB
Active(anon):    6621624 kB
Inactive(anon):  8402256 kB
Active(file):      89916 kB
Inactive(file):    38204 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       6211412 kB
Mapped:          1534592 kB
Shmem:           8812568 kB
Slab:             203244 kB
SReclaimable:     106932 kB
SUnreclaim:        96312 kB
KernelStack:       18736 kB
PageTables:        93880 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     8059084 kB
Committed_AS:   23933660 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     1761344 kB
DirectMap2M:    14704640 kB
DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
```

Comment: `swapon` should at least keep the system responsive.

Comment: @rastafile, swap would just increase total available virtual memory and then it can be used up too. One of my goals of working on live is not use disk (it can be or station can be diskless).

Comment: Working on live? That would explain a lot. I had a suse live USB, which worked quite fine, but firefox was very slow mostly. After a real install I realized how  big the difference is. To me it looks like some progs just need some normal disk space, they can't adapt to RAM/USB automatic.

Comment: @rastafile, as I see it no "RAM/USB automatic. " as `toram`, all distro unpacked to ram, interestingly Mint 18 took 6gb, 19 takes only 3. How they made it take twice as less? that is a question I have not asked yet.